# Set Theory problem regarding an empty family of subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the universe of discourse be the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers, and let $\mathbf A$ be the empty family of subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Show that $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}B = \mathbb R$.

**What does an "empty family of subsets" mean in this situation?**

Comment: The empty family of subsets is $\mathbf A=\varnothing\subseteq \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$. The two proofs you're asked for should be simple matters of unfolding the definitions of the indexed intersection and union notations. You have such definitions, don't you?

Comment: $A = \varnothing$

Comment: @HenningMakholm I believe I understand the concept of an intersection as it applies to indexed sets. However, when I visualize this pictorially, it seems to be counterintuitive that a family A = ∅ and yet its intersection is ℝ.

Also, why "empty family of subsets of ℝ"? I think A could be defined more simply as an empty set and still be the same thing.

Comment: @s_rc: When intersecting an empty family then every element from your universe vacuously satisfies the definition of that intersection. As for why phrase it like that, I suppose that it is because this question requires you to go over the definitions again, and whoever wrote it wanted to get you thinking a little bit before rushing to the definitions (I agree though, it's not the best phrasing and I'd have written $\varnothing$ directly).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you! I attempted it via 2-part proof in which ⋂B∈AB ⊆ ℝ and ℝ ⊆ ⋂B∈AB. I could manage the first part but not the second. Could you provide some direction?

Comment: @s_rc: Write out the definition for $x\in\bigcap_{B\in A}B$ (regardless to what $A$ is, the general definition).

Comment: @AsafKaragila {x: x ∈ B for every B ∈ A}. With A = ∅, I understand ∅ ⊆ ℝ, but I do not understand ℝ ⊆ ∅.

Comment: @seales: But the point is that $\bigcap_{B\in\varnothing}B=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid\forall B\in\varnothing, x\in B\}$. Do you know what a vacuous truth is?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I really do appreciate your help, but perhaps I'm being dense. I just read the wikipedia article on vacuous truth, and it is clear how this applies to ∅ ⊆ ℝ; (∀x)(x ∈ ∅ ⇒ x ∈ ℝ) - with the premise false, the statement is vacuously true. However, the reverse, ℝ ⊆ ∅, does not appear to be vacuously true: (∀x)(x ∈ ℝ ⇒ x ∈ ∅) - the premise is true and conclusion false.

Comment: But that's not what you're supposed to prove. You're supposed to prove that $\bigcap_{B\in\varnothing}=\Bbb R$. Not that $\varnothing=\Bbb R$. Don't confuse "$x\in\varnothing$" with "$x\in B$, for all $B\in\varnothing$".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed. This is my work thus far: (i) 1. Let x be an arbitrary element in ℝ. 2. Consider x ∈ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B ⇒ x ∈ ℝ. 3. Since the above statement is vacuously true, $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B ⊆ ℝ. (ii) 1. Let x be an arbitrary element in ℝ. 2. Consider x ∈ ℝ ⇒ x ∈ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B. 3. ??? - Are there mistakes up to ii-3? I don't see a way to proceed further.

Comment: Now you're confusing $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$. It is true that $\bigcup_{B\in\varnothing}\varnothing=\varnothing$. It's quite easy to prove. But $\bigcap_{B\in\varnothing}\neq\bigcup_{B\in\varnothing}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It was a formatting mistake. Could "x∈B, for all B∈∅", in the context of this proof, mean that since ∅ contains no sets, it, therefore, contains no B, and, thus, a real could exist within B because the above statement has no bearing on its contents?

Comment: @seales: How would you refute the claim $x\in\bigcap_{B\in\varnothing}$? Namely, when $x\notin\bigcap_{B\in\varnothing}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila It appears to me that $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}$B does not contain any x; therefore, a contradiction in which a claim that it does contain x only to show that x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}$ would be sufficient. I am having trouble visualizing $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}$B being equal to anything other than ∅. This intersection contains commonalities for all B ∈ ∅, but what commonalities can sets within ∅ share?

Comment: Just write down the statement $x\notin\bigcap_{B\in A}B$. You know what it means that $x$ is an element. Write the statement "$x$ is not an element of the intersection over $A$". (Forget what $A$ is in this context.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think I have made progress. (i) 1. Let x be an arbitrary element in $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B 2. Since the family A is empty, x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B. 3. Therefore, x ∈ ($\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B)ᶜ 4. By De Morgan's Law, ($\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B)ᶜ = $\bigcup_{B\in\mathbf A}$Bᶜ 5. Bᶜ = U - B 6. Since B is a set within an empty family, Bᶜ = U = ℝ. 7. Thus, for an arbitrary x in $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B, x ∈ ℝ. 8. Therefore,  $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B ⊆ ℝ.

Comment: Yes, that is progress, but it's not very far. That's the easy part of the inclusion. Since all sets concerned are subsets of $\Bbb R$ it's obvious the result is a subset of $\Bbb R$. Let me give you a push forward. We agreed already that given **any $A$**, we have $x\in\bigcap_{B\in A}B$ if and only if for every $B\in A$, $x\in B$. Therefore $x\notin\bigcap_{B\in A}B$ if and only if **NOT**(for every $B\in A$, $x\in B$). Now work on simplifying that negation. What do you get?

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you think? 1. Let x be an arbitrary element in $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B. 2. Since the family A is empty, x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B. 3. x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B iff ~(B ∈ A, x ∈ B) iff (B ∈ A) ^ ~(x ∈ B) iff (B ∈ A) ^ (x ∈ Bᶜ). 4. Bᶜ = U - B. 5. Since B is a set in an empty family, Bᶜ = U = ℝ. 6. x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B iff (B ∈ A) ^ (x ∈ ℝ). 7. Therefore x in $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B iff x ∈ ℝ. 8. Thus, $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}$B = ℝ.

Comment: You confuse $A$ with its elements. Forget the case that you're trying to solve. Just write the definition that I told you. Given $x$, what condition states that $x\notin\bigcap_{X\in D}$? (let's use other letters, too.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila my attempt at that was - "x ∉ $\bigcap_{X\in\mathbf D}$X iff ~(X ∈ D, x ∈ X) iff (x ∈ D) ^ ~(x ∈ X) iff (X ∈ D) ^ (x ∈ Xᶜ) iff (X ∈ D) ^ (x ∈ ℝ)"

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, my negation is wrong. Can (∀X ∈ D, x ∈ X) be thought of as (∀X ∈ D) ^ (x ∈ X)? If so, the negation would be (∀X ∈ D) ⇒ ~(x ∈ X) ⇒ (x ∉ X) ⇒ (x ∈ Xᶜ) ⇒  (x ∈ ℝ).

Comment: You have omitted the quantifiers. Don't omit the quantifiers, that is why you don't see the answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My attempt at negation is (∃X ∈ D)(x ∈ R)

Comment: You meant perhaps $x\in\Bbb R\setminus X$, I suppose. That's good. So in order for $x$ not to be in $\bigcap_{B\in\varnothing}B$, we need that **there exists $B\in\varnothing$ such that $x\notin B$**. Can that ever happen?

Comment: @AsafKaragila What is the meaning of "x ∈ ℝ ∖ X"? Particularly the "\ X".

Comment: It's what you write as $X^c$. The correct negation, by the way is $(\exists X\in D)(x\notin X)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does not (x ∉ X) = (x ∈ Xᶜ) = (x ∈ ℝ)?

Comment: This occurs when when x ∉ $\bigcup_{B\in\mathbf A}$B.

Comment: @seales: The first two are true, $x\notin X$ is the same as saying that $x\in X^c$. But $x\in\Bbb R$ is *always true* because all the sets we care about are subsets of $\Bbb R$. As for the second comment, yes, this occurs when $x\notin\bigcup_{B\in\varnothing} B$. But **can** that happen? Can **THERE EXIST** $B\in\varnothing$ to witness this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes; $\bigcup_{B\in\mathbf A}B$ = ∅ and, therefore, has no elements.

Comment: Is this another typo? Remember we are talking about the intersection, not the union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not a typo. I believed you to be asking about that set. However, x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf A}B$ iff x ∉ $\bigcup_{B\in\mathbf A}B$, right?. The truth of the former follows from the truth of the latter - which can be validated with any real.

Comment: What? Why would that equality be true? Unions and intersections have no reason to be equal in most cases. Look, you have the answer in the comments above. You have the definition of when an element is not in the intersection, and I asked you some guiding questions. Give them some thought. Especially the parts in boldface, sleep on it if you have to.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That seems obvious now. Regardless, I believe the reverse implication is true. Tomorrow indeed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Two more things. Thank you for your assistance. And, do you have any books, irrespective of topic, that you could recommend? A third item: I think you will make a good professor.

Comment: Feynman has some awesome memoirs. My students do like me, according to the anonymous feedback they give at the end of the semester. As for my help, you're the first one to insist on this. Most users give up in the middle, my rule is that I will bring you to the bar, but I can't make you drink. In other words, as long as you don't give up I am not giving up, but I don't plan on giving you the answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've read Feynman's book. What else? Not giving the answer is a good strategy. You remind me of the two authors, Simon Shocken and Noam Nissan. I believe one is a professor at your university. Their book, elements of computing systems, had a similar notion of you must do it yourself if you want to learn.

Comment: I haven't read books in a long long time now. 1984, and one book by H.G. Wells, don't recall the name but it was made into a decent movie with Brando and Val Kilmer. Speaking of movies with Brando, Heart of Darkness is nice: and Salman Rushdie wrote a book called Haroun and the Sea of Stories. Probably one of my favorite books.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What about this? I don't like the fourth step. 1. Let x be an arbitrary element. 2. Consider x ∉ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}B$ iff ~(∀B ∈ ∅)(x ∈ B) iff (∃B ∈ ∅)(x ∉ B). 4.(∃B ∈ ∅) cannot occur because ∅ has no elements. 5. Therefore, for an arbitrary x ∈ U, x ∈ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}B$. 6. Thus, U ⊆ $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}B$. 7. Because all sets are subsets of U, $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}B$ ⊆ U. 8. Therefore, U = $\bigcap_{B\in\mathbf ∅}B$.

Comment: Exactly! Very good!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I say that (∃B ∈ ∅) is not possible because there are no elements within ∅, but couldn't I just as well say the same for (∀B ∈ ∅)? How would you approach this proof?

Comment: No, because $\forall x\in X$ is a shorthand for $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow\ldots)$, so if $X=\varnothing$, the statement is vacuously true; whereas $\exists x\in X$ is a shorthand for $\exists x(x\in X\land\ldots)$, so if $X$ is empty it is provably false.

Comment: Good god, y'all.  Take it to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that $A$ is the empty set, $\varnothing$. It is a family of sets which has no members.